# Docker bind mount doesn't work when file is replaced

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have an **nginx** service in a `docker-compose.yml` file. The service is defined as follows:

```
server:
  container_name: myserver
  image: nginx:1.17.2
  volumes:
    - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - /var/log/nginx/access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log
    - /var/log/nginx/error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
  restart: always
  command: nginx-debug -g 'daemon off;'
  ports:
    - 80:80
```

In my `nginx.conf` file i have the following logging config :

```
## logging
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] [$server_name] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
```

I wanted to save the **nginx** access log in the host machine, and use **logrotate** in order to rotate the access logs daily. This is my **logrotate** config :

```
/var/log/nginx/access.log {
    daily
    rotate 4
}
```

The rotation part is working fine. I checked the rotation 3 days later and found the following files in `\var\log\nginx` :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Sep 28 03:34 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 170M Sep 28 15:24 access.log-20200927
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Sep 27 03:10 access.log-20200928
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.9K Sep 27 08:32 error.log
```

As you can see only the first file that was present when the docker-compose service was launched has data. the others are empty. I suspect that when **logrotate** replaces the `access.log` file with a new one, the bind mount stops working.

How can I work around this issue ? are there any solutions or better approaches for this ?

Thank you !

**EDIT :**

I have tried mounting the directory instead :

```
volumes:
    - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - /var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
```

When the log rotation happens, the same thing as before happens where `access.log` is empty and not receiving any logs. But now, instead of the logs not being saved anywhere anymore, the logs are saved but in the new renamed file `access.log-20200929` instead of `access.log`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Sep 29 01:59 access.log  <-- logs added here before rotation 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 187534973 Sep 28 17:12 access.log-20200927
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Sep 27 03:10 access.log-20200928
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21168025 Sep 29 02:00 access.log-20200929 <-- logs added here after rotation 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      3958 Sep 27 08:32 error.log
```

Restarting the service makes `access.log` receive the logs again

```
docker-compose restart myserver
```

So, I guess that I need to restart the compose service when the rotation happens. Is there a way to execute a command after log rotation happens ?. This may be too hacky for a solution. So, is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: typically you should mount the directory instead of the individual file, `logrotate` is going to rename then hup to get it to reopen the new file (leaving the old file as one of the postfixed ones)

Comment: @AnthonySottile I'm having another issue now, please check the edit on the question.

Comment: usually you should create a new question instead of editing in a second question to your question.  but you're missing `hup`ping the nginx process which should cause it to reopen the log files

Comment: Use "copytruncate" in your logrotate file so the file is not deleted and recreated.